# Maximum of $\operatorname{Tr}(\rho \circ \log \rho)$ using only linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{S}: \rho \in \mathcal{E} \mapsto-\operatorname{Tr}(\rho \circ \log \rho) \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of all self-adjoint such that $Tr(\rho)=1$ and $\left \langle \rho v,v \right \rangle>0$ of $L(V)$, $V$ a $\mathbb{C}$-space with $\dim V=n$.

Let $\rho$ self-adjoint and $Tr$ be trace of $\rho$. How I prove that maximum of $S$ is $\frac{1}{n}I$?

Comment: @user1551 I'm guessing the context of this is maximizing the von Neumann entropy for some density matrix $\rho$? In that case, assuming that $\rho$ is positive definite is probably reasonable. Though OP should elaborate on the context regardless.

Comment: oh, its positive definite, i forget

Comment: You can write the von Neumann entropy in terms of the ordinary entropy by considering the eigenvalues of $\rho$. This reduces the question to the question of why ordinary entropy is maximized for the uniform distribution and this can be done using e.g. a standard computation with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: is just a question with inner product in linear algebra, at least we cant use this big tool like lagrange multipliers.

Comment: could you show me this proof?

Comment: Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $\rho$. Since $f(x)=-x\log(x)$ is concave, $$\operatorname{tr}f(\frac{1}{n}I)=nf(\frac{1}{n})=nf(\frac{\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n}{n})\ge f(\lambda_1)+\cdots+f(\lambda_n)=\operatorname{tr}f(\rho).$$